# linkedin - import contact and send message using php or javascript

Tags: javascript, php, linkedin-api

How to import contact from linkedin and send message using php i have used

```
api_key: 'APIKEY'
authorize: true
credentials_cookie: true

 window.onload = function onLinkedInAuth() {
     // After they've signed-in, print a form to enable keyword searching
     var div = document.getElementById("sendMessageForm");

    div.innerHTML = '<h2>Send a Message To Yourself</h2>';
     div.innerHTML += '<form action="javascript:SendMessage();">' +
                  '<input id="message" size="30" value="You are awesome!" type="text">' +
                  '<input type="submit" value="Send Message!" /></form>';
 };

 function SendMessage(keywords) {
     // Call the Message sending API with the viewer's message
     // On success, call displayMessageSent(); On failure, do nothing.

     var message = document.getElementById('message').value; 
     var BODY = {
        "recipients": {
           "values": [{
             "person": {
                "_path": "/people/~",
             }
           }]
         },
       "subject": "JSON POST from JSAPI",
       "body": message
     }

     IN.API.Raw("/people/~/connections")
           .method("POST")
           /*.body(JSON.stringify(BODY)) */
           .result(displayMessageSent)
           .error(function error(e) { console.log(e);alert ("No dice"); });
 }

 function displayMessageSent() {
     var div = document.getElementById("sendMessageResult");
      div.innerHTML += "Yay!";
 }
```

referred from the url http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sample-code-sending-message

but was not successfull ..any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Did you load the linkedin Framework? It seems like you have deleted the section of code that load the framework and just put the api_key config settings inside a normal `<script>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to call the Linkedin js Framework.

In the example (from linkedin docs) of sample code provided, the **API KEY is commented!!**

You must put your api key and uncomment the code!

```
 <!-- Load in the JavaScript framework and register a callback function -->

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
   api_key: YOUR_KEY_HERE
   onLoad: onLinkedInLoad // optional param 
   authorize: true        // optional param
</script>
```

From Documentation in [Sample code sending-message](http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/sample-code-sending-message):

> The only **required** option is **api_key**, which is the API key you received
>   when you created an application

From here, you can copy/paste the code. With the code you have provided, maybe the problem was or the api_key or that you didn't call the script to load the API from LinkedIn.

Comment: Hi Lan, Thanks for the help when i tried to put the whole code i was seeing the linkedin sign in button when i click it i was able to login but was not able to see the send message div ..actually my purpose is to login to linkedin and get the usercontacts and send invitation from our website..thanks in advance

Comment: and when i login i still see the linkedin signup button..can u help me with more info..